# Migration from table to grid vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to simply create a table using vaadin with 2 rows and 3 columns to add to my existing interface. How can I do this with grid. I am new to Vaadin so can please anyone help me with this. I just want to add a table to my layout without adding data.

```
@Route("Playboard")
@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/style.css")
public class Playboard extends VerticalLayout {

public Playboard() {
    setLayout();
    addClassName("play-board");
    setSizeFull();

}

private void setLayout() {
HorizontalLayout playboard = new HorizontalLayout();
H1 text1 = new H1("Playerboard");
playboard.add(text1);
add(playboard);
addClassName("player-board");
setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

VerticalLayout n1 = new VerticalLayout();
Label label = new Label("Name :");
label.addClassName("player-name");
Label name = new Label("");
name.addClassName("players-name");
n1.add(label, name);
add(n1); }}
```

This my interface I need to get a table to be displayed here with 3 columns and 2 rows without any data. Can I display this in a vertical layout. Can you please help me with this.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What is your version of framework? Also, why do you want to use GridLayout and not Grid?

Comment: Are you looking for GridLayout or Grid? There are, at least, a lot of examples available in Vaadin's official documentation about Grid. What is the content of your cells? Is it a tabular data or some components? And what is the exact version you are using? Those pages might be helpful for Vaadin 10+: - [Java Examples for a Grid](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples)
- [ An introduction to Grid](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html)

Comment: Version 13. How can I do it using grid I am new to this can you please explain.

Comment: What type of data you have?

Comment: I just want to display a table in my layout without adding data how can I do this.

Comment: What is the purpose of you grid if it's empty? Could you elaborate a bit? Maybe Grid is not the best fit here then

Comment: Please add the code what you tried (e.g. the current code with the Table and your attempts to move over to Grid) and how it failed (errors, problems you faced, ...)

Comment: @cfrick I have posted the code below

Comment: SO is not a forum.  Please don't add to your question by writing answers. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57265719/edit) the question.

Comment: okay it was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

As other have stated, it is a little bit unclear if you want a layout for laying out components, or a grid for tabular data.

If you want tabular data, here is an example of a Grid with three columns and two rows.

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView(@Autowired MessageBean bean) {
        Button button = new Button("Click me",
                e -> Notification.show(bean.getMessage()));
        GridPro<Person> grid = new GridPro<>();
        grid.setItems(
                new Person("Steve", "Winchester", "Chengdu"),
                new Person("Bob", "Martin", "Turku");
        grid.addColumn(Person::getFirstName).setHeader("First name");
        grid.addColumn(Person::getLastName).setHeader("Last name");
        grid.addColumn(Person::getCity).setHeader("City");
        add(grid);
    }
}
```

Person is a plain Java object with the string properties firstName, lastName and city, with the associated getters and setters.